# Basic Analysis . Is there a contradiction in these two definitions of closed sets for the set $x_n=\{\dfrac {1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a contradiction in these two definitions of closed sets for the set $x_n=\{\dfrac {1}{n} : n \in \mathbb N\}$ ?

I happen to have a very basic query please.

Let $S$ be the set denoted by $\{\dfrac {1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Then $S^c$ is open as between any two members of $S$, we can find an open ball which lies completely inside $S^c$

Which means $S$ must be closed.

However, $S$ does not possess it's limit point $0$ which is contrary to the definition of a closed set?

Where could I be going wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the complement were open, you could find around _each_ $x\in S^c$ a ball that doesn't intersect $S$. Try to find such a ball for $x = 0$.

Comment: Your notation is not good: $\{1/n\}$ is a singleton set, consisting of just the single number $1/n$. You really should write something like $\{1/n\colon n=1,2,\ldots\}$ or $\{1/n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer right! I think the set is neither open nor closed . Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, like most subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, it is neither open nor closed.